# On which versions of windows we can run dot net application?

Tags: .net

On which versions of windows we can run dot net application, the platform is already having the .net framework installed. I mean on which windows version we can install .net fx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple google search yields: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|.net framework version| Comes preinstalled on| Can be installed on|
+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|4.7                   | 10 (1607)            | 7     onwards      |
|4.6                   | 10                   | Vista onwards      |
|4.5.1                 | 8.1                  | Vista onwards      |
|4.5                   | 8                    | Vista onwards      |
|4                     |                      | Vista onwards      |
|3.5                   | 7                    | Vista onwards      |
|3.0                   | Vista                | Vista onwards      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```